# Error when connecting to sql using Python

Tags: python, sql, python-db-api

I am using Python library pymssql to connect to a database. I have never used it before so the error might look trivial.

```
from os import getenv
import pymssql

server = getenv("192.xxx.xxx.xx") 
user = getenv("john.constantine")
password = getenv("xxxxxxx")

conn = pymssql.connect(server, user, password, "tempdb")
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT * from table')
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print row

conn.close()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Documents\Demo_DB.py", line 8, in <module>
    conn = pymssql.connect(server, user, password, "tempdb")
  File "pymssql.pyx", line 635, in pymssql.connect (pymssql.c:10734)
  File "_mssql.pyx", line 1902, in _mssql.connect (_mssql.c:21821)
  File "_mssql.pyx", line 552, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.__init__ (_mssql.c:5891)
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
```

I connect to DB using these credentials.
[image]

Comment: Your table in `tempdb` is called `table`?

Comment: @ShawnMehan The Table is under "Databases"

Comment: `server = getenv("192.xxx.xx.xx")` is going to set `server` to `None`, unless you actually have an environment variable named `192.xxx.xx.xx`. That's probably what's given you the None which is throwing the exception. (Same for your other `getenv`.)

Comment: @ShawnMehan  I have updated the question. That's how I connect to the DB.

Comment: @pbuck probably has it. print out the values that you get back from the `getenv`. Otherwise, you can place a break point in the init. I've been looking at the [code](https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/blob/master/src/_mssql.pyx) and I would step through it if it ain't a missing envvar

Comment: If you know the server address is `192.111.111.11`, why on earth are you calling `getenv()`?  Just do `server = '192.111.111.11'` and be done with it.

Comment: I was trying the exact thing from documentation. It worked. Thanks @JohnGordon

Comment: https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/example.py